# JavaScript dialy logging system

Tags: javascript, logging

I want to create a daily logging system for my project.
I'll overload the `console.log()` to make a line in the file and to output in the terminal.
For daily logging, we need something like a timer/time checker which checking if the date is another day.
What would be the best solution?
**Example file:**
**jsproject_20180702.log**

Comment: I did not want to use pre-made code.(like - *log4fs*)

Comment: I think it may help if you would take a look at the [**most popular logging frameworks/libraries on NPM**](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=logging&ranking=popularity) and just glance over on some of the source code to get some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on where you're planning to implement this functionality.

> Preferred option is to use your server module to trigger/schedule a function
>   which is executed everyday time interval.

**Option 1 - Javascript :**

Use `setInterval(backupLoggingFn, 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)`

**Option 2 - NPM :**

You can look into most popular logging frameworks/libraries on [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=logging&ranking=popularity)

**Option 3 - Linux Server:**

If your server is hosted on Linux server then you can do this by using simple **bash** [script](https://medium.com/@fotios.floros/linux-backup-script-1722cc9c2bf6).